# Must xml documents have a root tag?

Tags: xml

I wrote the w3cschool quiz on xml documents and it said I was wrong that xml documents need a root tag. After searching around I found [this article](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp) which states

> XML documents must contain one element that is the parent of all other
>   elements. This element is called the root element.

Isn't this a contradiction or what's the difference?

The result of the question on the quiz was

> 9. Which statement is true?
>
> You answered: XML documents must have a root tag
>
> Wrong Answer!

Comment: Yes, XML documents must have a *single* root tag, which is the parent of all other tags.

Comment: I just did the test. It doesn't seem to tell you what the right answer is. In question 9 it would be "All statements are true". So, what you selected is not generally wrong, it just wasn't the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you're referencing this question:

> 9. Which statement is true?
>
>    - XML tags are case sensitive
>    - XML documents must have a root tag
>    - All the statements are true
>    - XML elements must be properly nested

The answer is "All statements are true".

Comment: oh darn that's probably it

Comment: What does it mean MUST be properly nested. It would still be XML, just not properly formated if it wasn't. For example `<em><strong>emphasis and strong</em></strong>` I would say this is XML, just not properly formatted.

Comment: @Celeritas that isn't valid XML. No correct XML parser will accept it.